# Windows 8 store app c# animating margin

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

i am creating a windows store app and it needs some animation

does anyone have a working example of animating the margin of an usercontrol?

do i need to use reposition? ( doubleanimation doesn't support ucChat.margin or ucChat.margin.top)

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
                da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));
                da.From = 0;
                da.To = -400;

                Storyboard st = new Storyboard();
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, ucChat);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "ucChat.Margin.Top");
                st.Children.Add(da);

                st.Begin();
```

it seems that in wpf you could use ThicknessAnimation, is there an equivalent in windows store app?

Comment: his question is clear... i wish people on here stopped giving people a hard time for trying to ask a question. maybe he didn't phrase it perfectly but no need to be a jerk about